# C# data structure for storing lists of lists - lists will be variable sizes

Tags: c#, list, data-structures, collections

Need the lists to be indexed. So lists might be something like...

> BOB [mary, jose, bill, susie]
>
> KAREN [darlene, mike, scott]
>
> JUDY [steve]
>
> WARREN [phillip, matt]

Imagine it were a list of sites where live events were taking place. A query to it might be "hey, is KAREN hosting a group somewhere today?  If yes, is `scott` in her group"?

Would need the ability to add and remove groups, or members of groups.

What's the best way to accomplish this in C#?

**UPDATE:**  Based on comments below, let me elaborate.

There will not be high volumes of reads.   It's a chat app.  The groups are just that, private chat group threads.

What I'm trying to do is persist private thread membership across browser refreshes.  If BOB is looking at a live connected user list on his screen and he clicks on mary, then BOB has started a private thread with mary.  Their UI's reflect this.  I add a private chat tab to an area of their screens.  But if either refreshes their browser, I'd like the UI to recall from the server hub that they were in the middle of a private chat with the other.  My thought was that storing your private thread state on either chat client isn't good enough because when you refresh your browser it's gone.  Have to store it server side and recall it on client re-start.

So if 100 connected users are online, some number of private conversations of various sizes (maybe 3 in a group over here, maybe 7 in another group over there, maybe 2 over here, etc.) can be going on at any given time.  I need to persist that notion to a server for recall on client browser refresh. On refresh they just rejoin the group(s) they were last in.

The groups will likely be lists of session id's.  So let's say I'm looking at a screen of connected users and I pick mary out the list.  I'd want to create a new group server side containing my session id and hers.  Later jose joins us.  I'll want to add his session id to our thread's list.  If jose has to refresh his page for some reason, on refresh, he asks the server to see if his session id is in any chat groups right now.  Means his session id has to be searched for across all currently open private chat groups (what data structure would make this search easiest?).  If his session id is in a group, he re-joins it.  A tab for the conversation is created and the message history for the conversation is recalled and displayed.

Maybe jose was currently in 5 private conversations when he refreshed.  All should be properly reconstituted.

MS SignalR has the concept of groups.  Connection id's are used.  They don't persist across refreshes.  You get a new one when you reconnect so it's not an easy fit for persistence.  Session id is better.  I just need the right scheme to add, organize, search, and remove them.

Comment: there are too many different ways to do this to give you a specific answer List<List<object>> will work, as will using a dictionary, as will creating an object with a list as a property...

Answer (score 1):

If you're always going to have a name and a list of string, you might consider a `Dictionary`

```
Dictionary<string,List<string>>
```

Dictionaries allow you to access a particular value by using the key - so to access "JUDY" you'd use

```
myDictionary["JUDY"];
```

Obviously, the keys need to be unique.

Otherwise, you could create your own Object which contains a string ("Name") and List ("GroupMembers"). You could use linq to search easily using .Where() clauses

Otherwise pretty hard to know exactly what you want. What do you want to do with it? Many reads, few writes? Tell us more about your problem.

Comment: Told more about problem above.  Any thoughts?  Thanks